# Unable to view flag.txt using cat command

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am attempting to capture the flag for a challenge that requires command injection. I am able to view the text file flag.txt with the command $(ls ..)

[image]

but when I attempt to use cd or cat e.g. $(cat) or $(cd) I receive a message "command not found".

[image]

I have also tried all of the following:

```
$(ls .. | cat flag.txt)
$(echo $PATH)
$(cat flag.txt)
$(ls .. | echo $PATH)
$(pwd)
$(ls .. | pwd)
$(cd ..)
$(cd .. | echo $PATH)
```

I am wrapping the terminal commands $() because if I do not it'll post as a comment.

Here are the instructions for the challenge:

> In what we thought was an unrelated piece of intel, one of our field
> agents monitoring the gang reported this morning that he noticed one
> of them looking at a site that sells pencils. Well, it seems they're
> using it for something else too - to hide files.
>
> Luckily for us, we think the site is vulnerable to command injection.
> See if you can use the comment form to get access and find a file, we
> think it has a list of the gang members involved in the planned
> robbery and their particular role in the attack, so it's vital we get
> our hands on it right away.
>
> Tip: Find the file, it contains the flag.

I am not looking for an answer. Any suggestions or websites that can contribute to assisting me in finding a solution are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the file when running `ls ..` (whereever that idea came from)...

I.e. the file location is not `./flag.txt` (=`flag.txt`) but `../flag.txt`

```
$(cat ../flag.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the pipe `|` is invalid, if you want to chain commands use `;` or `&&` instead.

Comment: Make sure you are in the folder where flag.txt is, and run: `/bin/cat flag.txt` try also `/usr/bin/cat flag.txt`

Comment: when using ; && I receive the message 'No such file or directory and /bin/cat flag.txt and /usr/bin/cat flag.txt produce the same message.

Comment: Are you still with that?